# Require variable as parameter / argument in view?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to make a reusable view that takes a few variables as parameters. It's a struct, and I'd like for it to stay that way if possible. I'm aware of inout with functions, but don't know if there's an equivalent for this...

Currently, it works if I use the Void type, and do it that way, but I'm wondering if there's a "correct" way to do this.

I.e.

```
var item: Variable
```

I know that doesn't exist, but is there something similar?

[image]

Comment: show the code for "Variable" so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

After more reading, it seems I'm missing the point of Swift. I need to just create variable that want values that match the desired variable, and then pass the variable I want into those.

Comment: Can you write up a couple examples? I don't really get what you mean.